# How can I increase boundaries accuracy in satellite images?

Tags: graphics, image-processing

I use the following codes for this work on Mathematica, but they have low accuracy. I would be grateful if you could help me improve accuracy.
[image]

The codes are as follows

```
Pruning@Thinning@Closing[#, 5] &@DeleteSmallComponents[#, 500] &@
     LocalAdaptiveBinarize[#, 2] &@GaussianFilter[#, 10] &@img
```

[image]

```
ridges = ImageAdjust[RidgeFilter[imge, 7]]
```

[image]

```
bin = MorphologicalBinarize[ridges, {.1, .2}]
```

[image]

```
dist = DistanceTransform[ColorNegate@bin];
maxMarkers = MaxDetect[dist, 10];
HighlightImage[bin, maxMarkers]
```

[image]

```
watersheds = WatershedComponents[ridges, maxMarkers];
Colorize[watersheds]
```

[image]

Comment: Cross-posted: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2974609

Answer (score 4):

As a "quick and dirty” method `WaterShedComponents` works somewhat well with `Method -> {"MinimumSaliency", 0.5}` if we look at the total (rescaled) intensity of each pixel:

```
totImg = ImageApply[Total, img] // ImageAdjust;
WatershedComponents[totImg, Method -> {"MinimumSaliency", 0.5}] // Colorize
```

[image]

Now let's try to do better (this is hard!):

I am again going to use the total pixel intensity image `totImg`, and I will immediately apply the `RidgeFilter` first and `Binarize` it. The scale parameter for `RidgeFilter` and the threshold for binarize I just determined by eye by looking at different values with `Manipulate[ Binarize[RidgeFilter[totImg, r] // ImageAdjust, b], {r, 0, 5}, {b,  0, .3}]`

```
bestBin = Binarize[RidgeFilter[totImg, 3.5] // ImageAdjust, 0.15]
```

[image]

There is a lot of small noisy components in `bestBin` so I attempt to remove some of them with `DeleteSmallComponents`:

```
del = DeleteSmallComponents[bestBin, 100]
```

[image]

And now I use your same exact method (with the same parameter for `MaxDetect`) to get the markers for `WatershedComponents`:

```
dist = DistanceTransform[ColorNegate@del];
maxMarkers = MaxDetect[dist, 10];
HighlightImage[bestRidge, maxMarkers]
watersheds = WatershedComponents[del, maxMarkers];
Colorize@watersheds
```

[image]
[image]

This still only seems to be a mild improvement, and there's a lot of places the watersheds don't really line up with fields. Another function you may want to explore is
`ImageForestingComponents`:

```
ImageForestingComponents[del] // Colorize
```

[image]

**Update:** There is a lot of potential for improvement in my result. After playing with the parameters of `LocalAdaptiveBinarize` for some time I managed to get a good binarized ridge separation:

```
lab = 
 LocalAdaptiveBinarize[(RidgeFilter[totImg, 3] // ImageAdjust), 
  5, {1, 1.5, -.07}]
mc = MorphologicalComponents[bestBin] // Colorize;
SelectComponents[mc, #Count > 100 &]
```

[image]

[image]

Some squiggly lines still remain on the interior of fields in the final image, so I'm trying to think of an appropriate `ComponentMeasurement` I could use to remove these with using `SelectComponents`.